# vue-material table does not work with v-slot syntax

Tags: vuejs2, vue-material

I am using vue + vue-material to diplay a table.

on the vue-material docs i found, that rendering a table is very easy due to "slots" in vue [found here at "custom template"](https://vuematerial.io/components/table/) - so i gave it a go on a simplified example with just name+age of 2 people.

```
<template>
        <md-table v-model="people">
            <md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{ item }">
                <md-table-cell md-label="name">{{ item.name }}</md-table-cell>
                <md-table-cell md-label="age">{{ item.age }}</md-table-cell>
            </md-table-row>
        </md-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data: () => {
            return {
                people: [
                    {name: "Alice", age: 22},
                    {name: "Bob", age: 21}
                ]
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

works a treat. Then i looked up slots on the vue docs, and found there is a new syntax for [scoped slots on vue 2.6+](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots). So naturally i wanted to try it:

```
<template>
        <md-table v-model="people">
            <md-table-row v-slot:md-table-row="{ item }">
                <md-table-cell md-label="name">{{ item.name }}</md-table-cell>
                <md-table-cell md-label="age">{{ item.age }}</md-table-cell>
            </md-table-row>
        </md-table>
</template>
```

This does not render the table and also does not log any errors to the javascript console.

I found the place where this slot is defined [here](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/dev/src/components/MdTable/MdTable.vue) on the vue-material github, to verify everything would be set up according to the vue documentation:

```
 <tbody v-else-if="value.length">
          <md-table-row-ghost
            v-for="(item, index) in value"
            :key="getRowId(item, mdModelId)"
            :md-id="getRowId(item, mdModelId)"
            :md-index="index"
            :md-item="item">
            <slot name="md-table-row" :item="item" />
          </md-table-row-ghost>
        </tbody>
```

And yes, `slot name` is set, and `v-bind:item="item"` is also there, so as i understand, this should work with the new v-slot syntax.

Am I missing something?

EDIT.:

vue version 2.6.6
vue material 1.0.0.beta-10.2

I tried setting up a simple component defined just a slot (same name, also binding to :item) and wired it up using the "new" syntax - it worked.

appSlot:

```
<template>
    <div>
              <div v-for="name in names" :key="name">
                  <slot name="red-scope"
                        :content="name">
                  </slot>
              </div>
    </div>
<template>
```

where `names` comes via a property from AppWrapper:

```
<template>
    <AppSlot :names="names">
        <template #red-scope="{ content }">
            <p>hi {{content}}</p>
        </template>
    </AppSlot>
</template>
...
data() => {
    return {
        names: ["Alice", "Bob"]
    }
}
```

Does not make a lot of practical sense, but it verifies that my setup can handle the new syntax and it works

Comment: Gotta ask the question... are you using Vue 2.6+? This applies to any loaders (eg `vue-loader`)

Comment: i am using vue 2.6.6, vue-material 1.0.0-beta-10.2

Comment: Seems very odd given the onus of the new syntax is on the consumer, ie your code. The component in question does not need to change anything. Was this you? https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/2042

Comment: I'd say it's a problem with the compiled code that vue-material ships. It may be related to this Vue issue ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9458

Comment: Possible work-around is to import the `src` components instead of the `dist` ones. That or just keep using `slot-scope` for now.

Comment: @Phil the issue was me, yes. I can perfectly live with the "old" syntax, i was just wondering if i misunderstood how it was supposed to work